# Join statement in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I need to write Join statment after writing query in linq 
example :

```
var Query = (from Tab in Db.Employees
              select Tab)
```

as i have some cases to perform join operation so
i need to do it on this Query `Query.Join(Join with another Table like Department);` I need the Syntax

```
if (DeptID != -1){ Query.Join(Join with table Department where FkDeptID = DeptID); }
```

Comment: join with what? What other data?  We need more information.

Comment: You want to `Join()` to what?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the usage of join in the LINQ 'query syntax':

```
from t1 in db.Table1
join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}
```

Something like this?

```
var results = (from q in Query 
               join m in myList  on q.SomeID = m.SomeID
               select unknown);
```

Comment: i need user Join statment after performing Query as i have some cases to do that if(true){query.join(...)}

Comment: @Kareem : then you're going to have to update your question with an explicit set of source data and conditions. We can't read your mind!

Comment: i updated my question, are you understand what is in my mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
var Query =
    from e in Db.Employees
    join d in Db.Departments on e.FkDeptID equals d.DeptID into departments
    select new
    {
        Employee = e,
        Department = departments.SingleOrDefault(),
    };
```

This works assuming that when `e.FkDeptID == -1` that there is no record in the `Departments` table and in that case `Department` would be assigned `null`.

You should never have more than one department for an employee so I've used `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault`.